# How to draw rectangular box programmatically in javascript

Tags: dashcode

I am trying to draw the rectangular box on stacklayout's view programmatically (on runtime) using javascript so if any one has a solution for that please do tell me.

Thnx in advance

Parag

Answer (score 1):

place a canvas part on the view within stacklayout then use canvas draw functions from js;

```
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
var cxt=c.getContext("2d");
cxt.fillStyle="#FF0000";
cxt.fillRect(0,0,75,75);
```